# Reading multiple delimited protobuf messages from a file on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, protocol-buffers

I'm writing a tool for my master thesis, that needs to read protobuf datastreams from a file. Until now I worked exclusively on Mac OS and everything was fine, but now I'm trying to run the tool on Windows too.

Sadly on Windows I am not able to read multiple consecutive messages from a single stream. I tried to narrow the problem down and came to following small program that reproduces the problem.

```cpp
#include "tokens.pb.h"
#include <google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h>
#include <google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.h>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::fstream tokenFile(argv[1], std::ios_base::in);
  if(!tokenFile.is_open())
    return -1;
  google::protobuf::io::IstreamInputStream iis(&tokenFile);
  google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream cis(&iis);

  while(true){
    google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::Limit l;
    unsigned int msgSize;
    if(!cis.ReadVarint32(&msgSize))
      return 0; // probably reached eof
    l = cis.PushLimit(msgSize);

    tokenio::Union msg;
    if(!msg.ParseFromCodedStream(&cis))
      return -2; // couldn't read msg

    if(cis.BytesUntilLimit() > 0)
      return -3; // msg was not read completely

    cis.PopLimit(l);

    if(!msg.has_string() &&
       !msg.has_file() &&
       !msg.has_token() &&
       !msg.has_type())
      return -4; // msg contains no data
  }
  return 0;
}
```

On Mac OS this runs fine and returns 0 after reading the whole file as I expected.

On Windows the first message is read without problems. For the second message`ParseFromCodedInputStream` still returns true but does not read any data. This results in a `BytesUntilLimit` value that is larger than 0 and a return value of -3. Of course the message also does not contain any useable data. Any further reads from `cis` will also fail, as if the end of the stream was reached, even though the file has not been read completely.

I also tried using a `FileInputStream` with a file descriptor for input with the same result. Removing `Push/PopLimit` and reading data using `ReadString` calls with explicit message sizes and then parsing from that string also didn't help.

The following protobuf file was used.

```proto
package tokenio;

message TokenType {
    required uint32 id   = 1;
    required string name = 2;
}

message StringInstance {
    required string value = 1;
    optional uint64 id    = 2;
}

message BeginOfFile {
    required uint64 name = 1;
    optional uint64 type = 2;
}

message Token {
    required uint32 type   = 1;
    required uint32 offset = 2;
    optional uint32 line   = 3;
    optional uint32 column = 4;
    optional uint64 value  = 5;
}

message Union {
    optional TokenType      type   = 1;
    optional StringInstance string = 2;
    optional BeginOfFile    file   = 3;
    optional Token          token  = 4;
}
```

And [this is a sample input file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11648472/noop_main.c.tok).

The input file seems to be ok. At least its readable by the protobuf editor (on Windows and Mac OS) as well as the c++ implementation on Mac OS.

The code was tested:

- As working on Mac OS 10.8.4, compiled with Xcode 4.6.3 and protobuf 2.5.0
- As not working on Windows 8 64Bit, compiled with Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and protobuf 2.5.0

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `std::fstream tokenFile(argv[1], std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);`. The default is text mode; on Mac it doesn't matter, but on Windows you get CRLF sequences translated to LF, and ^Z (aka `'\x1A'`) character treated as end-of-file indicator.

Comment: @Igor Thank you very much. That actually was the problem. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it `std::fstream tokenFile(argv[1], std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);`. The default is text mode; on Mac and other Unix-like systems it doesn't matter, but on Windows in text mode you get CRLF sequences translated to LF, and ^Z (aka '\x1A') character treated as end-of-file indicator. Those characters might, by coincidence, occur in a binary stream, and cause trouble.